# SELECT MAX(TopDayScore) AS TopDayScore, Username FROM ERROR

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate-functions

I am getting an error when trying to run:

```
SELECT MAX(TopDayScore) AS TopDayScore, Username 
FROM Users 
WHERE PartnerID = '{0}' and Validated = 1
```

The error is:

> "Column 'Users.Username' is invalid in the select list because it is
>   not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

Not sure what i'm missing as I can't seem to find an example of mixing the MAX method with multiple properties.

Comment: hi, please send a your full query.

Comment: It seems you need to add the username in the group by clause

Comment: syntex is : select max(column) from tablename group by column. where username is not using for group by because only one max is come from group by, username is not under group by

Comment: Tnx for all the answers.  Looks like I need to do some reading to understand why things are the way they are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query can be the right one:

```
SELECT MAX(TopDayScore) AS TopDayScore, Username FROM users GROUP BY Username
```

Comment: Ok cool got it by doing: "SELECT MAX(TopDayScore) AS TopDayScore, Username FROM Users WHERE PartnerID = '{0}' and Validated = 1 GROUP BY Username"

Answer (score 2):

Anytime you use an aggregate (MAX, MIN, SUM, COUNT, etc.) in a `SELECT`, all columns not contained in some aggregate function needs to be in the `GROUP BY` clause, in this case, the Username column

```
SELECT MAX(TopDayScore) AS TopDayScore
,Username 
FROM Users 
WHERE PartnerID = '{0}' 
and Validated = 1
GROUP BY Username
```

Answer (score 1):

```
syntex is : 
    select max(column) from tablename group by column. 

where username is not using for group by because only one max is 
    come from group by, username is not under group by
```